# regex to find specific strings in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

*disclaimer - absolutely new to regexes....*

I have a string like this:

```
subject=something||x-access-token=something
```

For this I need to extract two values. `Subject` and `x-access-token`.

As a starting point, I wanted to collect two strings: `subject=` and `x-access-token=`. For this here is what I did:

```
/[a-z,-]+=/g.exec(mystring)
```

It returns only one element `subject=`. I expected both of them. Where i am doing wrong?

Comment: would probably be easier to split on the double pipe and then split on the equals sign for each

Comment: want to do it regex way...learning them :)

Comment: @scrappedcola is correct. Should use the correct tool for the job optimally. I'd use regex for actual pattern matching. http://regex101.com/

Comment: You would need to recall `exec()` for the next match, consider instead `"subject=something||x-access-token=something".match(/[a-z,-]+=/g)`

Answer (score 2):

The `g` modifier does not affect `exec`, because `exec` only returns the first match *by specification*. What you want is the `match` method:

```
mystring.match(/[a-z,-]+=/g)
```

Comment: This do answer my question precisely. However would like to get more enlightened. how do i start searching for a particular section using regexes. e.g here I was approaching it as first finding the string 'subject=' and then reading everything after that till i get a ||.

Comment: You can add `(.*?)(?=\|\||$)` to the end and the first capturing group would have your data.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to do it with a pure regexp:

```js
var input = 'subject=something1||x-access-token=something2'
var m = /subject=(.*)\|\|x-access-token=(.*)/.exec(input)
var subject = m[1]
var xAccessToken = m[2]
console.log(subject);
console.log(xAccessToken);
```

However, it would probably be cleaner to split it instead:

```js
console.log('subject=something||x-access-token=something'
      .split(/\|\|/)
      .map(function(a) { 
        a = a.split(/=/); 
        return { key: a[0], val: a[1] }
      }));
```

Answer (score 0):

No regex necessary. Write a tiny parser, it's easy.

```
function parseValues(str) {
    var result = {};

    str.split("||").forEach(function (item) {
        var parts = item.split("=");
        result[ parts[0] /* key */ ] = parts[1]; /* value */
    });

    return result;
}
```

usage

```
var obj = parseValues("subject=something||x-access-token=something-else");
// -> {subject: "something", x-access-token: "something-else"}

var subj = obj.subject;
// -> "something"

var token = obj["x-access-token"];
// -> "something-else"
```

Additional complications my arise when there is an escaping schema involved that allows you to have `||` inside a value, or when a value can contain an `=`.

You will hit these complications with regex approach as well, but with a parser-based approach they will be much easier to solve.

Answer (score 0):

You have to execute `exec` twice to get 2 extracted strings.

According to MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec

> If your regular expression uses the "g" flag, you can use the exec() method multiple times to find successive matches in the same string.

Usually, people extract all strings matching the pattern one by one with a `while` loop. Please execute following code in browser console to see how it works.

```
var regex = /[a-z,-]+=/g;
var string = "subject=something||x-access-token=something";
while(matched = regex.exec(string)) console.log(matched);
```

Comment: instead of running while loop, i just executed exec twice but got the same result. One element - ['subject=']. Testing in chrome console

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the string into a valid JSON string, then parse it to retrieve an object containing the expected data.

```js
var str = 'subject=something||x-access-token=something';
var obj = JSON.parse('{"' + str.replace(/=/g, '":"').replace(/\|\|/g, '","') + '"}');
console.log(obj);
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need regexp here, just use the javascript builtin function "split".

```
  var s = "subject=something1||x-access-token=something2";
  var r = s.split('||'); // r now is an array: ["subject=something1", "x-access-token=something2"]
  var i;
  for(i=0; i<r.length; i++){
    // for each array's item, split again
    r[i] = r[i].split('=');
  }
```

At the end you have a matrix like the following:

```
   y     x 0                1
   0       subject          something1
   1       x-access-token   something2
```

And you can access the elements using x and y:

```
"subject" == r[0][0]
"x-access-token" == r[1][0]
"something2" == r[1][1]
```